# Left/Right Limit Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Using a limit from the left and limit from the right argument, how can I see whether a limit exists for the following:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{|x|}$$

I think this limit does not exist by this argument, but how would I demonstrate that?

Comment: What do you think the limits from the left and right are?

Comment: I think -1 from the left and 1 from the right. Is it simple enough to say those are unequal, thus a limit DNE?

Comment: @PaulGerard Yes. If the limit exists, it has to be unique.

Comment: Those are right, and yes, it is. The key here is that $\sin x$ is very close to $x$ when $x$ is near $0$, so the fraction is very much like $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$.

Comment: ah i see, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin x}{-x}=-1$$

The above, of course, based in

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{ x}=1$$